# firebase-admin transaction hanging forever

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to safely mutate a document based on data from itself using a transaction. It runs once with the expected null value, but after that it hangs forever, never continuing, never running the callback again, not even running the `onComplete` callback, and the promise never even resolves or errors.

```
import * as fb from 'firebase-admin';

const fbApp = fb.initializeApp({
  projectId: 'my-project',
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseapp.com'
});

// ...

await fbApp
.database()
.ref(`services/${serviceId}`)
.transaction(async (service: Service | null) => {
  console.log(service); // This runs only once and prints null

  if(service) {
    // Perform logic and mutate `service`
  }

  return service;
}, (e, what, data) => {
  console.log(e, what, data); // This never prints
});

console.log('done'); // The promise never completes (with or without completion callback)
```